# Setting up Private External LateX Server/Distribution

Tags: overleaf

Have a synology NAS as well as a Raspberry Pi and I'm trying to set up Latex server so that I don't have to keep hosting this on my own system.  This would also let me manage a latex server without having to worry about reinstalling the entire latex server if I have to reset my computer, where I'd only keep the latex editor.

I'm good with hosting the server either on my raspberry pi or on my synology server (either through a docker container or without docker, I'm OK with either option, though docker would be preferred).

If anyone had successfully tried this in the past I'm all ears.  I'm not sure if sharelatex is the way to go for this...

Comment: What do you mean 'Latex server'? (La)TeX is just a command line tool that you run on `.tex` files to generate pdfs. Do you instead mean hosting a web platform for editing LaTeX like Overleaf? You can host your own https://github.com/overleaf/overleaf.

Comment: For Docker, have a look at https://gitlab.com/islandoftex/images/texlive

Comment: Okay after reading up some more, it might have to be overleaf and it would involve some hosting of a web platform.  I was hoping that I could point something like texstudio to an "external" tex repo, but I dont think that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay after further research it seems that what I was trying to do isn't possible, or if it is it is not easy to do.

I'll continue to keep a local copy of latex packages that I'd like on my system.  I have a way of keeping its size small.

For those interested: the solution for a network-hosted latex editor is indeed to use sharelatex or overleaf docker packages on a NAS or similar network device.  I did not attempt this option, but I'm sure many others in this place have.

Over and out...